# NodeJS Mapping API data from Fetch in a JS file to an EJS Table

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, coingecko

I have retrieved JSON data from Coingecko API, I wish to map it into a table on an ejs file, does anybody know how I would do so?

**GET for the EJS page with the API fetch inside (Located in a file called indexRoutes.js Location from root folder: routes/indexRoutes.js):**

```
router.get("/crypto", ensureAuthenticated,(req, res) => {
  async function getCoins(){
  const api_url =
  "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=gbp&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false";
  let fetch_response = await fetch(api_url);
  let json = await fetch_response.json();
  console.log(json);
  }
  getCoins();
  res.render("crypto");
});
```

**I have not yet added a table into the page but here is the already existing code on the page for reference. Filename (crypto.ejs) Location from root folder (views/pages/crypto.ejs):**

```
<%- include ("./includes/_header.ejs"); %>
<container class="pt-5">
  <div class="row mt-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center">Cryptocurrency Q&A</h1>
        <!--Accordian for Emissions Q&A-->
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div
            class="col-md-7 m-1 bg-white parathree text-black text-center p-3 mt-4"
          >
            <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                  <button
                    class="accordion-button collapsed"
                    type="button"
                    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="flush-collapseOne"
                  >
                    What is a Cryptocurrency?
                  </button>
                </h2>
                <div
                  id="flush-collapseOne"
                  class="accordion-collapse collapse"
                  aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne"
                  data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample"
                >
                  <div class="accordion-body">
                    <p>
                      A Cryptocurrency is a digital currency or a decentralized
                      system that has been secured by utilizing cryptography.
                      Cryptocurrency is seen widely as an investment platform
                      that is easily accessible as long as you are over the age
                      of 18. Cryptocurrency started because people were getting
                      fed up with the banks having control of all of their
                      transactions. Groups of cryptographers started to create
                      decentralized methods of payment called Cryptocurrencies,
                      none of the starting ones got enough momentum to become
                      big, until a still unknown identity named "Satoshi
                      Nakamoto" created what is now known as Bitcoin.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                      They wrote a piece of literature called "Bitcoin: A
                      Peer-to-Peer Electronic Cash System", which describes how
                      Bitcoin aims to create a decentralized version of the
                      financial sector which would once again empower the people
                      instead of the banks by using online payments that allow
                      Bitcoin. These decentralized systems are named
                      Blockchains. One downside to Cryptocurrency due to it
                      being electronic, it can be replicated easily until it is
                      worthless, therefore it must have limited supply and be
                      unique for it to be of any value.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
                  <button
                    class="accordion-button collapsed"
                    type="button"
                    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo"
                  >
                    What is a Blockchain and what are its benefits?
                  </button>
                </h2>
                <div
                  id="flush-collapseTwo"
                  class="accordion-collapse collapse"
                  aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo"
                  data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample"
                >
                  <div class="accordion-body">
                    <p>
                      Blockchains are essential for maintaining the "purpose" of
                      Cryptocurrency. They are essentially an electronic ledger
                      that contains all of the transactions made with every
                      Cryptocurrency whilst keeping the owner anonymous. The
                      wallet ID will be kept on each transaction, however, any
                      details that belong to the owner of said wallet will
                      remain unavailable. Therefore, hacking into somebody's
                      account is much harder.
                    </p>

                    <p>
                      For example, if someone tried to hack into your bank
                      account, empty it and change the data, it would be their
                      word against yours and the bank might assume that the
                      withdrawal was made by you as there is only one record to
                      change and the hacker would have changed it due to the
                      system being centralized, whereas with the Blockchain,
                      everybody who owns that Cryptocurrency, has a record of
                      the transactions made, therefore, the hacker would have to
                      change over half of the data, as Cryptocurrency decisions
                      are made final with over 51 percent of the record holders
                      opinions.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingThree">
                  <button
                    class="accordion-button collapsed"
                    type="button"
                    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#flush-collapseThree"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="flush-collapseThree"
                  >
                  How much of the economy consists of Cryptocurrency?
                  </button>
                </h2>
                <div
                  id="flush-collapseThree"
                  class="accordion-collapse collapse"
                  aria-labelledby="flush-headingThree"
                  data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample"
                >
                  <div class="accordion-body">
                    <p>Cryptocurrency is 7 percent of all of the worlds money in total</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="card card-body">
        <h1>Insert Table/List of top Cryptos here. (Using CoinGecko API)</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</container>
<%- include ("./includes/_footer.ejs"); %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change a couple things here.

To start you are receiving the response from the API, however you are not accessing the response outside of your nested function "getCoins". You will need to move your call to res.render() inside of the async function.

Once you have access to the data before the render, you can pass it to the ejs page by passing an object as a second argument to call to res.render().

After applying these changes your code will look something like:

```
router.get("/crypto", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  async function getCoins(){
  const api_url =
  "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=gbp&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false";
  let fetch_response = await fetch(api_url);
  let json = await fetch_response.json();
  console.log(json);
  res.render("crypto", { data: json });
  }
  getCoins();
});
```

Now that you have data passed to the page, you should be able to access it in between the code tags:

```
<%= data.whateverIsInside %>
```

And that should allow you to display it on the page. Would recommend checking out these resources on EJS:

https://ejs.co/#docs

https://github.com/mde/ejs/wiki/Using-EJS-with-Express

Comment: That's great help, however, after that, the data from the API is an array of objects, Bitcoin, Ethereum , XRP etc, how would I add them all in separate rows of a table into the ejs from the js file? I am new to web development so the simple things really screw with me.

Comment: You can define a loop in ejs like so:
`<% for (var i = 0; i < reports.length; i++) { %>
*HTML that you want to render here*
<% } %>`

Comment: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/ejs+foreach+loop

Comment: @Erratic if this helped an upvote would be appreciated :)

Comment: I tried to upvote but it says I need 15 rep first, sorry, when I get enough ill come back and upvote!.